# how to a call listener of view from controller in extjs

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I made a bar column chart using ExtJs mvc. Now in the controller I want to add a function for click event to catch the selected value of the column. Here is my controller code:

```js
Ext.define('Gamma.controller.ControlFile', {

  extend : 'Ext.app.Controller',

  //define the stores
  stores : ['BarColumn','RadarView','VoiceCallStore','SMSCallStore','MMSCallStore','GPRSUsageStore'],
  //define the models 
  models : ['BarCol','radar','VoiceCallModel','SMSCallModel','MMSCallModel','GPRSUsageModel'],
  //define the views
  views : ['BarColumnChart','LineChart','RadarChart','VoicePie','SMSPie','MMSPie','GPRSPie'],

  init : function() { 
    this.control({

    });
  }
});
```

Please any one help me.

Comment: I got the answer.. it is in the link-- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16387114/how-to-call-a-listener-of-view-from-controller-in-extjs/16398559?noredirect=1#16398559

Answer (score 1):

- On chart:

```js
listeners : {

    itemmousedown : function(obj) {

               this.fireEvent('itemmousedownchartbar',obj);

        }
}
```

At final on chart defined, after `this.CallParent()`:

```js
this.addEvents('itemmousedownchartbar');
```

- Now, on Controller:

```js
'barChartView' : {

     itemmousedownchartbar: this.function_to_call

}
```